# Unable to run Lambda function from .zip file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So im trying to run python on my Lambda function but since i need dependencies/libraries i decided to look into it and found the [oficial documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html).

So i follow the steps:

```
mkdir aws_env
cd aws_env
virtualenv .
source /bin/activate
pip install package_name
deactivate
```

After this i just copied the lambda.py file into the root of aws_env folder which has a line that goes:

```
def lambda_handler(event,context):
     #Do Stuff
```

After this i just .zip everything and uploaded it to Lambda.

[image: aws_env]
[image: lambda.py]

But when i run it i get:

> {   "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda'" }

And i ve checked the configuration, everything seems Ok

[image: lambda configuration]

Any idea why im having this issue?

-- EDIT:

Just tried doing:

```
cd /aws_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages
zip -r9 aws_env.zip .
cd ~
zip -g aws_env.zip lambda.py
```

instead of compressing the whole folder but im still getting the same error.

Comment: did you step through the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example-deployment-pkg.html#with-s3-example-deployment-pkg-python ? specifically, steps 8 and 9.. the note is to zip the contents not the dir

Comment: I was actually not following those steps and i just did but im still getting this error. Thanks anyway. @mad.meesh

Comment: i searched the error on google, seems to be common issue.. for example here is one thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228386

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your lambda.py in the main dir of the function not in Lib

Comment: more of a comment rather then an answer